# Variável soma está acumulando o valor ao invés de iniciar em zero

Tags: python, python-3.x

O algoritmo é para o cliente realizar pedidos em uma lanchonete, ele pede o nome do cliente - 1, em seguida a quantidade do pedido e depois o algoritmo pede para digitar o número do pedido, quando o pedido encerra o programa da o valor total do pedido e passa para próximo cliente - 2, quando o cliente – 2 encerra o pedido o algoritmo pega valor total do cliente 1 soma com do cliente 2 e da valor total dessa soma para cliente 2 em vez dele só da o valor puro para cliente 2

```
print('-' * 20)
print('{:^20}'.format('LANCHONETE'))
print('-' * 20)
print('''Cardapio
[1] - Esfirra R$ 3,50
[2] - Coxinha R$ 3,50
[3] - Hotdog R$ 4,00
[4] - Hamburgue R$ 7,00
[5] - Suco R$ 1,50''')
valor = soma = 0
while True:
    print('-' * 20)
    nome = str(input('Digite seu nome: '))
    quant = int(input('Digite a quantidade do pedido: '))
    print('-' * 20)
    for c in range(1, quant + 1):
        pedido = int(input(f'Digite o {c}° pedido: '))
        if pedido >= 1 and pedido <= 2:
            valor = 3.50
        if pedido == 3:
            valor = 4
        if pedido == 4:
            valor = 7
        if pedido == 5:
            valor = 1.50
        soma += valor
    print(f'O valor total do pedido é R${soma:.2f}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Isso porque você iniciou o valor de `soma` fora do laço de repetição, então o valor irá se acumular durante as iterações. O que você precisa fazer é iniciar a `soma` em zero para cada novo cliente, dentro do laço de repetição.

Ao invés de:

```
soma = 0
while True:
    ...
```

Faça:

```
while True:
    soma = 0
    ...
```

Comment: Deu certo obrigado!

Comment: Não esqueça de avaliar a resposta